# <DateTimeInput> converts time to UTC when saving

Tags: react-admin

Thanks for adding DateTimeInput! I have a bit of a problem with it, though. It converts the entered time into UTC using my local timezone (decreases 2 hours from the entered time). Is there a way to make it simply save the time that's entered? 
I didn't find any info about any options this component accepts.

EDIT:
Nobody has any answer to this problem? I'm sure I'm not the only one who wants to be able to store date/time values from the UI "as-is", instead of some automatic conversions. 
In our case we enter certain measurement data from different locations. The location of the UI user here is irrelevant and the automatic conversion simply messes things up.

Comment: Are you sure you want every client to store values in their own time zone?

Comment: Yes. We have automatically stored data that uses the local time. We are adding a form to add similar data manually, so the time has to match the automatically collected data.

Comment: OK. I just asked because in a distributed system with severs an clients normally there is no such thing like a single local time zone. E.g. browsers get their time zone from the operating system's user account. This time zones may vary between different clients. So when you display values stored by another client you might either see wrong values or have violated the happens-before semantics of associated events.

Comment: To be exact, we don't want every client to store values in their own time zone. We actually want everyone to store values in UTC. We don't want any conversions to happen at all.